# Is MotionX GPS capable of caching Google Maps Tiles?

Tags: iphone, applications, gps, google-maps

I've read this post here: [How can I save Google Maps in iOS for offline use?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5252/2160) but it didn't mention anything about MotionX GPS caching Google Maps tiles. I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that it can cache proprietary tiles or Bing tiles or something, but can it cache Google tiles? That would be sweet if it could!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the MotionX GPS manual](http://gps.motionx.com/iphone/manual/11_onboardmaps.php):

> Unfortunately due to Microsoft restrictions on Bing maps and Google restrictions on Google maps, these maps types can't be cached or stored onboard. By contrast, MotionX road and terrain maps may be cached and downloaded.

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to know that. I'll just use AccuTerra then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Previous answer was correct that it is against the terms of service and licensing agreements, but incorrectly answers the OP's question.

The application is (successfully) able to cache Google map tiles (specifically, terrain in the below example) with the following URL scheme: http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x=[X]&y=[Y]&z=[Z].

Comment: As of March 23, 2015 this address scheme for Google Maps does not seem to work.  It seems the Google Maps tile server has changed, the correct address to plug into MotionX is now: https://mts1.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x=[X]&y=[Y]&z=[Z]