# Best offline maps for iOS 4.2.1 (iPod 2G)

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ipod-touch, maps

I have a jailbroken iPod touch 2G running iOS 4.2.1. I tried City Maps to go and oMaps. First on did not work, second one did not offer much functionality. Is there any other app that I can try?

EDIT: Lower version of City Maps to Go works on iOS 4.2.1!!!

Comment: What functionality do you want given you say "one did not offer much"

Comment: Its quite some time now since I posted the question (I think June 28).. At that time, City Maps to go didn't work when I tried it with the latest version. Also, I think oMaps didn't allow me to pinpoint my location on the map or didn't show Points of Interest, something like that. Hence I said "one did not offer much". Can't recall what exactly it was :-)

Comment: *"Lower version of City Maps to Go works on iOS 4.2.1"* - That is totally useless info unless you specify which version number. Please?

Comment: As it was a jail broken iPod touch, I am not sure if I remember the version number I downloaded from apptrackr. Besides, the question is a year old and I've moved to newer iPhone :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple apps you can try:

- [OpenMaps](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/openmaps-free/id359719250?mt=8)
- [OfflineMaps](http://www.htmlremix.com/iphone/offline-map-in-iphone)
- [MapsWithMe](http://www.mapswithme.com)
- [CityMaps 2 Go](http://itunes.apple.com/app/city-maps-2go/id327783342) (not sure if this is the one you've mentioned in your opening post)

And there is a big discussion about saving [Google Maps for offline use](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5252/how-can-i-save-google-maps-in-ios-for-offline-use). So maybe there's a solution for you too?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

[Offline+Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/app/offline+maps/id502648393)

> Offline+Maps is the perfect tool to save maps and consult them offline.

## or

[City maps 2 Go](https://itunes.apple.com/app/city-maps-2go/id327783342)

> Interactive offline map PLUS Wikipedia travel guides for the whole world. INCLUDING unlimited map downloads. 100% offline. No data roaming or WiFi required. The most downloaded app of its kind. Ideal for trips abroad and at home.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [MotionX GPS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/motionx-gps/id299949744?mt=8) - AppStore says it will run on iOS 4.0 but
I've never tried it myself on anything less than an iPhone 3GS.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.. Will try it at home and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I use [MapsWithMe](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/id510623322?mt=8) paid version. Although the app doesn't provide navigation, it's quite useful alternative to paper maps. Allows using maps offline, search for POIs and bookmark places. And the main advantage for me is the simplicity and fast work.